# Why is space significant in this ruby method call?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a jsonify view in a Rails application. I have:

```
json.samba_secrets_present(not @idp_ad_info.samba_secrets.nil?)
```

That produces a syntax error:

```
app/views/idp_ad_infos/show.jsonify:7: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('
```

However,

```
json.samba_secrets_present (not @idp_ad_info.samba_secrets.nil?)
```

works fine. I would have expected that the first would be a method call to the `samba_secrets_present` method on the `Jsonify::Builder` object with a first argument of `not idp_ad_info.samba_secrets.nil?`. Why is the space significant?

Comment: Maybe this is the old `not` operator bug, e.g., `puts(not true)` fails, but `puts((not true))` works fine. I'd forgotten about that. (Or not a bug, as shown in the answers, but a parsing thing?)

Comment: Totally unrelated, but what's the use case of using of `not` over `!` ? Another SO answer says that `!` has the highest precedence and `not` has one of the lowest precedences ... but I'm still trying to find a reason to use `not`. I'd rather use parentheses to force the desired order of operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
puts(not true)  #=> error
puts (not true) #=> false, CASE 2
puts(not(true)) #=> false
```

Ruby allows you to omit the parenthesis to call a method sometimes. Generally, if there's only one method call, you can omit the parenthesis. However, you cannot omit that when the method call is at the argument position of another method call (*general case, see special case in Update section*) because that would introduce ambiguity. Consider the following example:

```
puts(not true, false)
puts(some_method arg1, arg2)
```

The Ruby parser cannot determine whether the `false` (or `arg2`) is a argument of the inner method, or the outer `puts`, so it raises an error for these case. The parser doesn't have runtime context to determine the arity of the inner method, so it doesn't care whether it's a unary method (like `not`) or not.

Take `CASE 2` as an example, that's interpreted as:

```
puts( (not false))
```

And you can write:

```
puts (not false), true, (not true)
```

they're all arguments to `puts`.

[Some Ref: Positional Arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Positional+Arguments)

**Update:**
*toro2k* commented that `puts(system 'ls')` works. That's because `system` accepts `*args` which will grab all the rest arguments. There won't be any arguments left for the outer method, definitely :). As a result, there's no ambiguity in that case.

```
def a *args
  args
end
p(a 1, 2, 3, 4) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, I'd vote to write clearer code with necessary parenthesis to make the code more readable.

Comment: What I don't get is: why `puts(not 'ls')` is a syntax error and, for example, `puts(system 'ls')` is not?